# implementing QUIC protocol in mininet

Tags: linux, mininet, quic

I'm trying to run QUIC in mininet(miniedit in specific) and going through some troubles here.

I've downloaded QUIC toy server&client from chromium.googlesource.com
Ran eth it mentioned including simple tests and it worked just fine.
Now I want to run QUIC in mininet using miniedit, which is a GUI tool for mininet, based on the server&client I've downloaded and yet I failed to find a clue on how.
I merely assume that I have to associate QUIC with hosts on the network topology and I just don't know how.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Miniedit as far as I know is a GUI environment for network topologies. If you want to run your custom server and client you are better off using the python API that mininet provides. Setup two hosts, connect them, run the server on one of them, then run the client on the other.

You can find more about the python API on the [mininet tutorial page](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#part-4-python-api-examples)